# Remove Entries From TreeMap, getting java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, iterator, treemap

I am trying to remove some entries from TreeMap using some logic. This my code

```
TreeMap<String, Object> treeMap = someEntries();
Iterator<Entry<String, Object> iter = treeMap.entrySet().iterator();
Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = null;

while ((entry = iter.next()) != null) {
    if (!entry.getKey().contains(search)) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

getting Exception:-

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1113)
    at java.util.TreeMap$EntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1151)
    at java.util.TreeMap$EntryIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1146)
```

What is that Exception? This is the error during iteration. Please also suggest me a right way.

Comment: `(entry = iter.next()) != null`... when the iterator has no more elements, `iter.next()` won't be `null`, but instead throw the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking for the next element like this:

```
    TreeMap<String, Object> treeMap = someEntries();
    Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> iter = treeMap.entrySet().iterator();
    Entry<String, Object> entry;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        entry = iter.next();
        if (!entry.getKey().contains(search)) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```

If you call `iter.next()` when there is no next element, the `NoSuchElementException` gets thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking with `Iterator#hasNext()` not `Iterator#next()` like so:

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    entry = iter.next();
    if (!entry.getKey().contains(search)) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you traverse to the last element, the 'next' point is NULL, so you will get NoSuchElementException when you go to the end. 
Use the following code to have a try:

```
TreeMap<String, Object> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
treeMap.put("a", 1);
treeMap.put("b", 2);
treeMap.put("c", 3);
treeMap.put("d", 4);
Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> iter = treeMap.entrySet().iterator();
Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = null;

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    entry = iter.next();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    if (!entry.getKey().contains("a")) {
           iter.remove();
    }
}

System.out.println("-----");
iter = treeMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    entry = iter.next();
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
}
```